# find unique values row wise on comma separated values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, row, unique

For a dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['abc,def,ghi,jkl,abc','abc,def,ghi,def,ghi']})
```

How to get unique values of the column `col` row wise in a new column like as follows:

```
          col             unique_col
0  abc,def,ghi,jkl,abc    abc,def,ghi,jkl
1  abc,def,ghi,def,ghi    abc,def,ghi
```

I tried using `iteritems` but got Attribute error :

```
for i, item in df.col.iteritems():
    print item.unique()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['abc,def,ghi,jkl,abc','abc,def,ghi,def,ghi']})


def unique_col(col):
    return ','.join(set(col.split(',')))

df['unique_col'] = df.col.apply(unique_col)
```

result:

```
    col     unique_col
0   abc,def,ghi,jkl,abc     ghi,jkl,abc,def
1   abc,def,ghi,def,ghi     ghi,abc,def
```

Comment: if you prefer to sort the result: 

def unique_col(col):
    return ','.join(sorted(set(col.split(','))))

Comment: @Ifkopp Thanks ...this works. Kindly give me a link or description so that  one colud learn more on `return ','.join(set(col.split(',')))`  :)

Comment: How would you do this and preserve the original order, the first example doesnt guarantee any sort order, the second sorts alphabetically afterwards, i am keen to preserve the original order